# Is it possible to copy /paste multiple lines of text into cells of org-mode table?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Here is my question, I have multiple lines of text, line this:

```
line1
line2
line3
...
```

And I want to create a org-mode table like this:

```
| C1    |
|-------|
| line1 |
| line2 |
| line3 | 
| ....  |
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, that's possible:

1. Select lines you want to add to the table.
2. Press <kbd>C-c |</kbd> (`org-table-create-or-convert-from-region`). This will give you:

   ```
   | line1 |
   | line2 |
   | line3 |
   ```

Now all you need to do is add the header line. Here's one way of doing that:

1. With point (the cursor) on `line1`, press <kbd>C-o</kbd> (`org-open-line`), then enter `C1`.
2. Press <kbd>C-c -</kbd> (`org-ctrl-c-minus`) to insert the separator.

Answer (score 11):

Let's say you have an empty table as shown below and you want to paste few lines in column *C1*.

```
|----+----|
| C0 | C1 |
|----+----|
|    |    |
|----+----|
```

#### Step 1: Copy the lines as a rectangle

Copy the lines using `copy-rectangle-as-kill` (`C-x r M-w`) or cut them using `kill-rectangle` (`C-x r k`). Below shows the point and mark locations I used when copying/cutting the rectangle.

```
▯ine1
line2
line3▮
```

#### Step 2: Make space for the lines to be inserted in the table

```
|----+----|
| C0 | C1 |
|----+----|
|    |▮   |
|----+----|
```

With the cursor in the desired column as shown above, call `org-open-line` for the required number of times. For this example, we'll call it twice.

```
|----+----|
| C0 | C1 |
|----+----|
|    |▮   |
|    |    |
|    |    |
|----+----|
```

#### Step 3: Paste the rectangle

Paste the rectangle using `M-x yank-rectangle` or `C-x r y`. That will give you:

```
|----+----|
| C0 | C1 |
|----+----|
|    |line1    |
|    |line2    |
|    |line3    |
|----+----|
```

Hit `C-c C-c` to auto align the table.

```
|----+-------|
| C0 | C1    |
|----+-------|
|    | line1 |
|    | line2 |
|    | line3 |
|----+-------|
```

Comment: This solution worked better for me because my lines had org dates in them.