# Why is a TAB character added when using kill-rectangle and yank-rectangle to insert multiple rows into an org-mode table?

Tags: org-mode, org-table, copy-paste, tabs

I noticed an annoying behaviour when copying multiple rows (a list) from a web page into an org-mode table, following a process inspired by [Is it possible to copy /paste multiple lines of text into cells of org-mode table?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9613/is-it-possible-to-copy-paste-multiple-lines-of-text-into-cells-of-org-mode-tabl).

The annoying result is that the table sides don't align properly, due to a TAB character being introduced during the process. Maybe I've discovered a bug or an undesired feature.

Note: It seems that using `copy-rectangle-as-kill` rather than `kill-rectangle` in the process prevents the TAB from appearing.

### Reproducing the behaviour

**Update**: Reproduced in Emacs 26.3, but not fully in 27.1. If you have Docker installed you can test yourself using: `docker run -it silex/emacs:26.3 emacs`.
For version 27.1, do `docker run -it silex/emacs:27.1 emacs` and note that when yanking, a TAB character is actually created/inserted after the `A`. However, when you then press `C-c C-c` the TAB is replaced with a suitable number of spaces.

Create an empty table and these lines of text (the number of characters matter):

```
|   |
|   |

A
12345678
```

Cut/kill the lines as a rectangle in exactly the following way:

- Start `rectangle-mark-mode` (`C-x SPC`) with the cursor to the left of `A`
- Use `kill-rectangle` (`C-x r k`) with the cursor to the right of `8`

Yank rectangle into the table:

- Place cursor on first row
- Do `yank-rectangle` (`C-x r y`)

It should now look like this:

```
| A   |
| 12345678  |
```

There should be a TAB character after the `A` in the first row.
With cursor in table, align borders using `C-c C-c`, giving:

```
| A  |
|  12345678 |
```

Oops, still unaligned.

### Discussion

I suspect the misalignment is due to the TAB character. But to see the effect, you have to have the right number of characters on the second row. Repeating steps above on the following two lines of text produces an aligned table without a TAB character:

```
A
1234567

| A        |
| 1234567  |
```

Further, using `copy-rectangle-as-kill` (`C-x r M-w`) on the original two lines of text also did not result in a TAB character.

Comment: I can't replicate the "Oops, still unaligned." in Emacs 27.1 with its standard org version.  It aligns it correctly.  GNU Emacs 27.1, Org mode version 9.3.

Comment: Same here. I started Emacs 27.1 with `emacs -Q` and didn't get the "Oops, still unaligned." part. @chr could you please start Emacs by executing `emacs -Q` and tell us whether you still get the error?

Comment: Hmm, this is weird.  I am unable to replicate in a new Emacs. However, I can still replicate the behaviour in my old running instance of Emacs (version 26.3), that was started on 4th of January. The laptop has been up for 20 days. And I did mess a bit with the Emacs configuration relatively recently, e.g. pulling in new versions of 'org' and 'org-plus-contrib'.  So I may well have done something to e.g. cause an invalid configuration.   My apologies for not testing in a fresh Emacs before posting!

Comment: Ok, get's weirder...   Turns out my original Emacs was started with 'emacs -q'. I don't remember why at all.  However, if I start with `emacs -q` I can replicate the behaviour.  I can also replicate the behaviour on another computer (also version 26.3).  I also could replicate on a third computer.    Could you please give it a try with '-q'?    Note: Don't do my mistake an try and replicate with only '1234567', it needs eight characters on the second row.

Comment: Not sure what's going on. Just now I could reproduce it on version 26.3 using `emacs -Q` but not `emacs`. Using `emacs -Q`, the yank command inserts a TAB. Using `emacs` does not insert a TAB.

Comment: I just downloaded Emacs 27.1-1 on macOS and tested it. There, with or without `-q`, a TAB is inserted when yanking, _but_ `C-c C-c` replaces the TAB with spaces so the table borders line up.  However, if I use `copy-rectangle-on-kill`, when yanking I do not get a TAB.  So when trying to reproduce it's good to highlight TABs, and pay attention to if the second row is `1234567` or `12345678`. It seems it's only in the latter case you get a TAB character.

Comment: In this [GIF](https://s2.gifyu.com/images/sendcd5d129b8e3ccc46.gif). You can see that a TAB is indeed (as reported by `what-cursor-position` (`C-x =`)) inserted after pressing `C-x r y`. However, after `C-c C-c` is pressed, the table is well aligned. Note that emacs was started with `-q`. I'm using Emacs 27.1.